# JSP modelAttribute set value in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

am having jsp form with modelAttribute and while submit the form I need to set few other values in the same modelAttribute and send it to spring,

```
<form:form name="myForm" modelAttribute="item">

    $('#submit').click(function() {
            var values = $("#item").serialize();
                values = {
                    type : "New Item"
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type : "post",
                    data : values,
                    url : "/myApp/submit.do",
                    success : function(msg) {
                        jQuery("#msg").html("Form submitted");
                    }
                });
            });
```

Here 'type' is another setter method inside 'item' modelAttribute and while submit the form I need to set the value for 'type'. If I do like,
values = {
                type : "New Item"
            };
then other setter methods become null and only setting the value for type='New Item';
Please kindly help me on this. Thank in Advance.

Comment: can you please try this values.type = "New Item" instead of `values = {
                    type : "New Item"
                };`

Comment: Thanks Mondal, I tried this but here the type is null and other values are getting passed.